# Timer interval with 2 NSDateComponent

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have two nsdatecomponent object, and I want a substract the time of my first object with the time of the seconde object.

example: DateComponentObject1 = DateComponentObject1 - DateComponentObject2

so, if I have 3 hour in DateComponentObject1 and 1 hour in DateComponentObject2, I have 2 hour at the end in the DateComponentObject1.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create an `NSCalendar` object that corresponds to the calendar used by your `NSDateComponent` instances.
2. Convert `DateComponentObject1` to an `NSDate` with `-[NSCalendar dateFromComponents:]`.
3. Multiply all values in `DateComponentObject2` by `-1` (because you want to subtract them from the first date).
4. Add the inverted `DateComponentObject2` to the date object with `-[NSCalendar dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:]`.
5. Split the resulting `NSDate` object into date components with `-[NSCalendar components:fromDate:]`.